# Spivak Chapter 1 Problem (i)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Prove $$\left| xy \right| = \left| x \right|   \cdot \left| y \right|$$

Spivak's proof:

> $(\left| xy \right|)^{2} = ( xy )^{2} =  x ^{2} y ^{2} = (\left |x\right | ^{2} \left | y\right | ^{2}) = (\left |x  \right | \cdot \left | y \right|)^{2}$

> Since $\left| xy \right|$ and $\left |x  \right | \cdot \left | y \right|$ are both $\geq 0$, this proves that $\left| xy \right| = \left| x \right|   \cdot \left| y \right|$

This proof forms the basis for most of the proofs that follow, so I really want to carefully understand a few concepts.

1. What allows us to assume that $\left|xy \right |$ is $\geq 0$? Of course the construct $\left|xy \right |$ tells us this is the absolute value of $xy$, and indeed the definition shows us that $$\left| xy \right| = \begin{cases}
    xy, \qquad xy \geq 0 \\ 
    -xy, \qquad xy \leq 0
   \end{cases} $$ but that is not what Spivak says. Can someone weigh in?
2. I can more readily accept that $\left |x  \right | \cdot \left | y \right|$  is $\geq 0$ as this occurs subsequent to $(xy)^{2}$

This might seem rather trivial to most of the seasoned on this board, but getting a good foundation I think is crucial.  Thanks for your help, as always.

Comment: The assertion $|xy| \ge 0$ (and indeed $|x| \ge 0$ and $|y| \ge 0$) would need to be proven separately (such as from the definition). It certainly doesn't follow from Spivak's argument.

Comment: @TheoBendit  That's exactly what I thought!

Comment: @user1115542 To fill in the gaps, we first prove that for all $z$, $|z| \geq 0$. We know that either $z \leq 0$ or $z \geq 0$. If $z \leq 0$, then $|z| = -z \geq 0$. And if $z \geq 0$, then $|z| = z \geq 0$. From here, we see that $|xy|$, $|x|$, and $|y|$ are all $\geq 0$. Thus, $|x||y| \geq 0$.

Comment: @MarkSaving That makes perfect sense. I think what Spivak does, in a rather terse way, is at some point prove something, then simply assume it to be true later. That is something that I will simply have to get used to. And, sometimes it is not all that obvious why he does something, (not a criticism), but more a desire to understand his thinking.

Answer (score 2):

As noticed in the comments $|xy|\ge 0$ and $|x|,|y|\ge 0$ can be easily proved separetely by the definition.

As an alternative proof we can show that

- for $xy=0 \implies 0=|xy|=|x||y|=0$
- for $xy<0 \implies -xy=|xy|=|x||y|=-x \cdot y=-xy\quad \lor \quad  -xy=|xy|=|x||y|=x \cdot -y=-xy$
- for $xy>0 \implies xy=|xy|=|x||y|=x \cdot y=xy \quad \lor \quad  xy=|xy|=|x||y|=-x \cdot -y=xy$

therefore $|xy|$ is equivalent to $|x||y|$.

Comment: Thank you. And, if fact, the idea of using cases is also suggested by him in the text of Chapter 1. He does allude to the idea of using the ‘square’ concept by noting that $|a| = \sqrt {a^{2}}$ and I suppose this use in this case allows the framework to “reassemble” $|xy|$ as needed in the proof.

Comment: @user1115542 I am a big fan of using $\sqrt{x^2}$ as your non-piecewise definition of $|x|$,

Comment: @Alan It is rather elegant, is it not?

Answer (score 1):

From Calculus by Spivak, Chapter 1, Page 11 (3rd edition)

> For any number $a$, we define the **absolute value** $|a|$ of $a$ as follows:
>
> $$|a| =
> \begin{cases}
> a, & a \ge 0 \\
> -a, & a \le 0.
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Note that $|a|$ is always positive, except when $a = 0$.

This holds for any real number, including $x$, $y$, and $xy$.

$|xy| \ge 0$ *by definition*.

As for your comment that

> I can more readily accept that $|x|\cdot|y|$ is $\ge 0$ as this occurs subsequent to $(xy)^2$

there is a different and I think simpler argument that you may be missing:

By definition $|x|$ and $|y|$ are each $\ge 0$. The product of two nonnegative numbers is always nonnegative because:

- If either one is zero, the product is zero ($0\cdot a = 0$ for any number $a$.)
- If neither is zero, they are both positive and so their product is positive (closure under multiplication).

Comment: Thanks Ben. Indeed, my argument does fall away completely when one understands what you and others have explained.

Comment: Don't be discouraged. The beginning is the hardest part! Take your time with it.

Comment: Also, you are right: Spivak frequently uses results from previous problems without comment or citation. For this reason, problems are perhaps best tackled in order, without omission.

Comment: Yep...that is what I am doing. Thanks for your kind words.